Remmina doesn't respond to "press enter"
Here's how I install Remmina (from Remmina wiki)
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next
sudo apt update
sudo apt install remmina remmina-plugin-rdp remmina-plugin-secret

I am trying to connect to the remote:
$ remmina
remmina-Message: 10:**:**.*69: Remmina does not log all output statements. Turn on more verbose output by using "G_MESSAGES_DEBUG=remmina" as an environment variable.
More info available on the Remmina wiki at:
https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/wikis/Usage/Remmina-debugging

(org.remmina.Remmina:7653): Gtk-WARNING **: 10:**:**.*18: gtk_menu_attach_to_widget(): menu already attached to GtkMenuItem


Displays:

But it doesn't respond when I hit Enter as if I didn't hit the key. No error message in the log either.

Have you seen this? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/remmina/+bug/2062177 I do not know if the version number is lower in snaps or not.
